# can I shorten this regular expression using intersection?

Tags: javascript, regular-language, string-length

I have this language L that contains only one string:
[image]
written more concisely [image]

This string has 2(2^n−1) characters and I want to reduce it.
I was thinking of using intersection, if i can find some regular languages in which the intersection of their regular expressions will yield this string.

I have here the recursive function in case that would help:

```
function recursiveRegex(charset) {
if(charset.length == 0) {
    return [];
} else {
    var char = charset.splice(charset.length - 1, 1);
    var returnVal = recursiveRegex(charset);
    return returnVal.concat(returnVal) + char ;
}
}

console.log(recursiveRegex(['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']));
```

Comment: and what is your question ?

Comment: Could you show us the grammar that uses intersection to describe your language?

Comment: Assuming that you can use the intersection operator in your regular expressions.
I want to shorten this regular expression by intersecting languages of different sorts using those n symbols to produce the string.

Comment: why you not set parameters of function as `function f(begin,end)` ?

Comment: can you elaborate please

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/k4jX6/) doing what you need ? i not very good in math :), anyway you should get the idea

Answer (score 3):

This is NOT a regular language, so you cannot find a regular grammar to define it.

Consequently, there is no regular expression for this language.

```
A_1: a_1

A_2: A_1 A_1 a_2

A_3: A_2 A_2 a_3

A_n: A_{n-1} A_{n-1} a_n
```

This grammar defines your language and it is not a regular grammar.

A direct proof that this grammar does not define a regular language is that one needs more than a constant number of locations of memory to define the language. For a given `N`, one needs a number depending on `N` to keep the `N`th word .

---

Consider each left symbol a location of memory. If you want to make it regular, you should have a finite number of rules. If you need to make it finite, it should be done so:

ATOM: a1

RULE_{n+1}: ATOM | RULE_n RULE_n a_{n+1}

To create correctly this language, you would need a counter , in order to know what `a_n` to insert at each moment. But it is not possible to create counters of any kind using regular grammars.

Comment: hmm, are you sure it's not. The language only contains that string. If you would be kind enough to provide your proof. I simply want a shorter way of describing this language using the standard operations (concatenation, union and Kleene star) and intersection to reduce the length of the string.

Comment: How does that grammar generates the string there is only two symbols there a1 and a2 while the string has a1 until an